# Hide php code for certain customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, customer-group

How can I hide the php code below from certain customer group ids 5,6,7? My code below of what I have thus far.

```
<?php
    $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
if($isLoggedIn):
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    if(in_array($customerGroupId, array('5','6','7'))):

                <?php  if($quotedFeeType == 'fob' && $code != "flatrate") continue; ?>
                <?php  if(($quotedFeeType == 'ddp' || $quotedFeeType == 'cif') && $code != "tablerate") continue; ?> 
        endif;  
 endif; 
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: I've edited your question with the use of in_array. Take a look if it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as the following:

```
/* 1 - Check if customer is logged in */
$isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
/* If customer is logged in */
if($isLoggedIn) :
    /* 2-  Get the logged in customer's group ID */
    $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    /* 3 - Check if the logged in customer's group ID matches with the ID you are after */
    /* Customer group IDs are listed against each group under Admin > Customers > Customer Groups */
    if(in_array($customerGroupId, array('5','6','7'))) :
        // Your Code Here
    endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);  
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && ($group->getCode()!=5 && $group->getCode()!=6 && $group->getCode()!=7)):

// Will not been visible to customers in group 5,6 or 7

endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $groupIds = array(generalGroup=>'5', specialGroup=>'6', customGroup=>'7'); ?>

<?php if (!array_search(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(), $groupIds)) : ?>
      // The code to hide...
<?php endif;?>
```